# CSS hover effect does not move smoothly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, transactions, transform

As my title says, when I try to hover on my container, it instantly scales up instead of smoothly transitioning from its original size. I am using transform and transition in my css.

JS Fiddle of the code: https://jsfiddle.net/1kbtjaLs/

Hover effect:

```
  .card:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
    -o-transform: scale(1.05);
    transform: scale(1.05);

    -webkit-transform: all .3s ease-in-out time;
    -moz-transform: all .3s ease-in-out time;
    -ms-transform: all .3s ease-in-out time;
    -o-transform: all .3s ease-in-out time;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out time;
  }
```

the ease in out does not seem to be functioning as intended.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this below code

**css**

```
 .card {
    width: 350px;
    transition: 0.5s all ease 0s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s all ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s all ease 0s;
    -ms-transition: 0.5s all ease 0s;
}
.card:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
    -o-transform: scale(1.05);
    transform: scale(1.05);
    transition: 0.5s all ease 0s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s all ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s all ease 0s;
    -ms-transition: 0.5s all ease 0s;
}
```

Comment: thanks, the ease-out is not necessary after all

Answer (score 2):

Several problems:

1. `transition` property should be on `.card` instead of `.card:hover`
2. `time` value in `transition` is invalid, `time` should be in sec to specify the delay(If this is what u try to achieve)
3. Remove all the `transform: all ease-out....` because it is also invalid, keep only `transform: scale(1.05)` part.

Answer (score 1):

You have no defined `time` variable (used in `transition: all .3s ease-in-out time`); changing this to `.3s` will show your smooth transition, as expected.

Note, however, that the transition will still 'jump' back when you lose the hover. To also transition smoothly in this case, you'll also want to apply the styles to `.card`:

```css
.container-membership {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

;
.list-group-item {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 0px;
}

.price {
  font-size: 72px;
}

.currency {
  font-size: 25px;
  position: relative;
  top: -30px;
}

.card {
  width: 350px;
  -webkit-transform: all .3s ease-in-out .3s;
  -moz-transform: all .3s ease-in-out .3s;
  -ms-transform: all .3s ease-in-out .3s;
  -o-transform: all .3s ease-in-out .3s;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out .3s;
}

.card:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
  -o-transform: scale(1.05);
  transform: scale(1.05);
  -webkit-transform: all .3s ease-in-out .3s;
  -moz-transform: all .3s ease-in-out .3s;
  -ms-transform: all .3s ease-in-out .3s;
  -o-transform: all .3s ease-in-out .3s;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out .3s;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body class="bg-color-white">


  <div class="container container-membership">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-offset-3">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header text-center">
            <h3 class="price"><span class="currency">USD</span>49</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="card-block text-center">
            <br>
            <div class="card-title">
              <h4>Plan 1</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
                aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
            <br>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br><br>
</body>

</html>
```